# videos not getting uploaded on server

Tags: php, video, file-upload

I had a form through which the user could upload videos and store them on the server folder

```
<form action="insertvideo.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn green"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Submit</button>
</form>
```

insertvideo.php page

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("mp3", "mp4", "wma");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
            }
        else
            {
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
                echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

                if (file_exists("extra/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                    {
                        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                    }
                else
                    {
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                        "extra/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                        echo "Stored in: " . "extra/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                    }
            }
    }
else
    {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
?>
```

I have 2 videos of .MP4 format, one is of smaller size and other has larger size.  For testing purpose i haven't place any code that checks the size of the video, but still video of larger size is not getting uploaded.

can anyone please tell why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $new_path = '.extra/';
    $target_file = $new_path . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $ext = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $allowed_ext = array("mp3", "mp4", "wma");

    if (in_array($target_file, $allowed_ext))    {

        if(file_exists("extra/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "extra/".$_FILES["file"]["name"].$ext);

            echo "Stored in: " . "extra/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
?>
```

and in `php.ini`

```
file_uploads=On
upload_max_filesize=20M
```

[PHP `in_array()` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp)

Comment: it is still not working, I have edited my last part of the post can you please go through it once

Comment: i am getting this response.. Upload: video.mp4 Type:  Size: 0 Kb
Temp file:  Stored in: extra/video.mp4

Comment: in php ini file_upload is on??

Answer (score 0):

Increase the max upload size and post size in php.ini

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '400M');
post_max_size = 10M
```